# filter dataframe using python skill list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have list of skills. I am trying to filter POS_NNP column. If word is in skills then (word,1) else (word,0) and in this format [(word1,1),(word2,0),(word1,1)....] for each row.

Some of the words in skills are [Machine Learning, Artificial Intelligence, Python(Programming language)....]

I have created a if-else but it is throwing error and I dont understand how to fix it.

```
sample['skill/notskill']=sample['POS_NNP'].apply(lambda x:','.join([(x,1) if x in skill else (x, 0)]))
```

Can someone please guide me

Comment: can you provide sample dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
df['skill/notskill']=df['POS_NNP'].apply(lambda x: [(word,1) if word in skill else (word,0) for word in x.split() ])
```

You might need to split the word into multiple words in df['POS_NNP'] to be able to compare.